# Order child model by parent attribute in has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want to order **children** by **parents' names**.

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, -> { order(:name) }
end

class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope { order(:name) }

  has_one :child
end
```

But

```
Child.includes(:parent).as_json(include: { parent: { only: :name } })
```

doesn't return the correct results.
Is there any good way for this?

Comment: can you just do: `@children = Child.all.includes(:parent).order("parent.name desc")`

Comment: @ruby_newbie I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: I edited the other comment.  Ultimately I would define a scope on children called "by_parent' that returns this query.

Comment: @ruby_newbie, can you share the scope?

Comment: Child.all.includes(:parent).order("parent.name desc") is not correct since parent table doesn't exist. Also .all is not needed. So Child.includes(:parent).order("parents.name desc") is correct. Thank you!

Comment: Oh yeah sorry forgot the s.  Also remember that if you declare a default scope and you make "by_parent_name" you may need .reorder.  I added an answer below to make this post clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Child.includes(:parent).order("parents.name desc").as_json(include: { parent: { only: :name } })
```

This worked for me.